# Add parent folder name to file name?

Tags: powershell, scripting, rename, parent-child

I have this folder structure

```
root\1\2\3\1.txt
root\3\2\4\6\1.txt
```

I want to rename text files to `root_1.txt`
I tried

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse *.txt | Rename-Item -NewName %{$_.Parent.Parent.Name + $_.Name}
```

But this doesn't work because Parent work only for directories

Answer (score 3):

For file items, use the `Directory` property:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse *.txt | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Directory.Parent.Name + $_.Name}
```

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon thanks, was copied from the OP and I didn't check it

Answer (score 0):

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse *.txt | 
    Where-Object { ($_.FullName | Split-Path -NoQualifier ) -match '^\\(.+?)\\' } | # Get root folder using -match and regex
    Rename-Item -NewName { $Matches[1] + '_' + $_.Name } -WhatIf    # Build new name from $Matches[1] and filename
                                                                    # Remove -WhatIf after testing
```